# How to sanitize strings in Golang striping html, javascript, sql etc

Tags: go, serialization, strip-tags

I'm writing a REST API, through which users can register/login and a number of other things that would require them to send JSON in the request body. The JSON sent in the request body will look something like this for registering:

```
{
    "name": "luke",
    "email": "l@g.com",
    "date_of_birth": "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
    "location": "Galway",
    "profile_image_id": 1,
    "password": "password",
    "is_subscribee_account": false,
    "broker_id": 1
}
```

This data will then be decoded into a struct and the individual items inserted into the database. I'm not familiar with how I should sanitize the data to remove any Javascript, HTML, SQL etc that may interfere with the correct running of the application and possibly result in a compromised system.

The below code is what I have currently to read in and validate the data but it doesn't sanitize the data for html, javascript, sql etc.
Any input would be appreciated on how I should go about sanitizing it. The REST API is written in Go.

//The below code decodes the JSON into the dst variable.

```
func (app *application) readJSON(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, dst interface{}) error {
    maxBytes := 1_048_576
    r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, int64(maxBytes))

    dec := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    dec.DisallowUnknownFields()

    err := dec.Decode(dst)
    if err != nil {
        var syntaxError *json.SyntaxError
        var unmarshalTypeError *json.UnmarshalTypeError
        var invalidUnmarshalError *json.InvalidUnmarshalError

        switch {
        case errors.As(err, &syntaxError):
            return fmt.Errorf("body contains badly-formed JSON (at character %d)", syntaxError.Offset)

        case errors.Is(err, io.ErrUnexpectedEOF):
            return errors.New("body contains badly-formed JSON")

        case errors.As(err, &unmarshalTypeError):
            if unmarshalTypeError.Field != "" {
                return fmt.Errorf("body contains incorrect JSON type for field %q", unmarshalTypeError.Field)
            }
            return fmt.Errorf("body contains incorrect JSON type (at character %d)", unmarshalTypeError.Offset)

        case errors.Is(err, io.EOF):
            return errors.New("body must not be empty")

        case strings.HasPrefix(err.Error(), "json: unknown field "):
            fieldName := strings.TrimPrefix(err.Error(), "json: unknown field ")
            return fmt.Errorf("body contains unknown key %s", fieldName)

        case err.Error() == "http: request body too large":
            return fmt.Errorf("body must not be larger than %d bytes", maxBytes)

        case errors.As(err, &invalidUnmarshalError):
            panic(err)

        default:
            return err
        }
    }

    err = dec.Decode(&struct{}{})
    if err != io.EOF {
        return errors.New("body must only contain a single JSON value")
    }

    return nil
}
```

//The below code validates the email, password and user. If the first parameter in V.Check() is false the following two parameter are returned in the response to the user.

```
func ValidateEmail(v *validator.Validator, email string) {
    v.Check(email != "", "email", "must be provided")
    v.Check(validator.Matches(email, validator.EmailRX), "email", "must be a valid email address")
}

func ValidatePasswordPlaintext(v *validator.Validator, password string) {
    v.Check(password != "", "password", "must be provided")
    v.Check(len(password) >= 8, "password", "must be at least 8 bytes long")
    v.Check(len(password) <= 72, "password", "must not be more than 72 bytes long")
}

func ValidateUser(v *validator.Validator, user *User) {
    v.Check(user.Name != "", "name", "must be provided")
    v.Check(len(user.Name) <= 500, "name", "must not be more than 500 bytes long")

    ValidateEmail(v, user.Email)

    if user.Password.plaintext != nil {
        ValidatePasswordPlaintext(v, *user.Password.plaintext)
    }

    if user.Password.hash == nil {
        panic("missing password hash for user")
    }
}
```

How do I serialize the struct data with this in mind? So it wont cause issues if later inserted in a webpage. Is there a package function that I can pass the string data to that will return safe data?

Comment: The stock [`html/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template) provides proper sanitization with escaping for HTML and JS.

Comment: And for protecting against SQL injection you should use parameter placeholders appropriate for the specific db backend you're using.

Comment: Looks like `name`, `email`, and `location` are the only free-form fields you'd ever output anywhere to need sanitization. I hope and assume you'll be salting  & hashing so the content doesn't need sanitizing. Names, email addresses, and locations should be safe to scrub of any characters that would make HTML/JS/SQL dangerous - single/double quotes, semicolons, angle brackets. Those probably shouldn't be in those fields even if you're not worried about injection attacks.

Comment: This question is too vague to answer.

Comment: You cannot sanitize data for all possible uses on the input side because you may eventually want to use it in a format that hasn't been invented yet (YAML is comparatively young, for instance). You must escape if and when you use this data for the context it is used in. As others have already commented, the html/template and database/sql packages provide facilities to handle user-supplied data safely.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback guys. Really helpful.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for the feedback. Is it regarded best practice to salt and hash general data like name, email, location or would that be a bit of overkill? I understand why you would salt and hash a password.

Comment: You can only salt & hash data you don't need back in its original form (i.e. passwords).